# Angular routerLinkActive is matching exact route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Running Angular 8. My main navigation has a set of links one being, for example `/services`. On that page are services. When a user clicks "Production" it goes to the url `/services/production` however, the "Services" nav item loses it's active state.

I've applied `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}"` to attempt enforce the active classes on non-exact routes but it's not maintaining the active state.

the routes for these are in their individual directories so "services" has a `services-routing.module` that handles it's routing. However the navigation links are the root/app level.

I think I need load those routes into the `app-routing.module` but not sure how to go about that, if that's the case.

When attempting to lazy load the routes I get the error:

```
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
```

I double checked and made sure I'm only importing `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` at the `app.module` level.

--- edit

I have the routes lazy loading but that didn't resolve it. `/services` shows active but `/services/production` doesn't

--- edit

app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: 'access-denied', component: AccessDeinedComponent }
];
```

app.component

```
this.navLinks = [
  { path: '/about', label: 'About', icon: 'assessment' },
  { path: '/contact', label: 'Contact', icon: 'assignment' },
  { path: '/services', label: 'Services', icon: 'settings' }
];
```

app.component.html

```
  <nav class="nav-tab-group" mat-tab-nav-bar color="accent">
        <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
        [routerLink]="link.path"
        routerLinkActive="mat-tab-label-active active-link"
        class="subnav-link">
        <mat-icon class="tab-icon">{{link.icon}} is view</mat-icon>
        <span class="link-text" >{{link.label}}</span>
    </a>
  </nav>
```

services-routing.module (in a different directory)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ServicesComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { roles },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'services/production',
        component: ProductionComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        data: { roles }
      }...
    ]
  }
];
```

So the actual route behavior in in the services-routing.module and the nav in in the root app.component scripts. When I"m at the services root, the services `routerLink` is active but all children it's inactive.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've landed on is adding my active link class conditionally:

`[ngClass]="{'active-link': setActiveNav(link)}"`

my `navLinks` variable has an addition `string[]` that hold other acceptable paths, for example `['/services/production']`.

The method that returns true looks for the existence of additional paths and check if it exists in `location.path()` using the Location class from `@angular/common`. It also checks against the expected path.

I also have an situation where a nav item needs to be "active" on a completely unrelated URL.

```
  setActiveNav(navLink): boolean {
    const currentPath = this.location.path();
    let foundPath = false;
    if (navLink.additionalPaths) {
      navLink.additionalPaths.forEach(path => {
        if (currentPath.indexOf(path) >= 0 || currentPath.indexOf(navLink.path) >= 0) {
          foundPath = true;
        }
      });
    } else if (currentPath.indexOf(navLink.path) >= 0) {
      foundPath = true;
    }

    return foundPath;
  }
```